# Windows: Is it possible to set .ini files and .xml files to have different icons?

Tags: windows, desktop-icons

(Windows 11) I am working with quite a lot of `.xml` files as well as other text files so I thought it would be good to change the icon for `.xml` files so that they stood out.

When I changed the `.xml` filetype icon using [filetypesman](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/file_types_manager.html) `.ini` files were also affected and have the xml icon. Is it possible to have them separated so that they have different icons?

I don't know if any other file types were changed too, but `.txt` files were not.

Comment: icon are displayed by the linked icon-display program. What are you using to edit the xml and ini files? try changing one to use a different editor.

Comment: @user165568 Thanks, but what you are saying doesn't seem relevant to this problem.

Comment: You asked if it was possible: I suggested a possible method. Try it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is very possible.
Windows 11 uses a "perceived type" for xml and ini file extensions via the registry which is slightly different than the old/original method.

***The original method still works just fine.***

Understand that the newer fairly worthless explorer that uses this junk actually can do things that take advantage of this but I doubt this will affect you.

***For the sake of this demonstration, I will use XML.***

First we are going to back up the keys so if you don't like the result, you can put it all back.

### Backup

1. Open regedit
2. Navigate to `Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.xml` select `File` from the menu and `export`.  Name it `xml_backup` (or bobzyeruncle++ for all I care).
3. Navigate to `Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\xmlfile\ShellEx` select `File` from the menu and `export`.  Name it `xmlfile_backup` (or notafan for all I care).

### Fix the keys

1. Navigate to `Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.xml`
2. Delete everything but the `(default)` key and the `Content Type` key.
3. Change the `(default)` key data (which is empty) to `xmlfile`.
4. Navigate to `Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\xmlfile\ShellEx`.  Either delete the key or rename ShellEx to something else.  I suggest renaming it to `SenorCmasMasSucksShellEx`
   .
5. Restart the explorer.  You will see that the icon it is now using is under `Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\xmlfile\DefaultIcon` and not attached to the same thing as an ini file.  It will be an ugly icon from IE.

Now, using the `Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\xmlfile\DefaultIcon` key, you can choose any icon path you like.

### Handy trick you might already know

To close the explorer:  click on taskbar.  alt-f4.  ctrl-alt-shift when clicking cancel.
To open a new explorer: ctrl-shift-esc -> process tab -> run new process -> explorer.exe.
Prevents the need to logout and back in.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't expecting it to be possible, so this is great. I'll try this soon before accepting your answer.

Comment: there is a larger understanding you could have here too @paradroid.. for instance.. we picked "xmlfile" because it already exists and had the keys setup.. you can make anything you want dating all the way back to win95.